# How do I implement a robust Data Persistence Layer in C++?

Tags: c++, design-patterns, database-connection, dao, data-access-layer

I am at the first time creating a huge program in C++ for my company and I want to create a good pattern to connect into my MySql db. I have these problems:

> -I can't decide which pattern should be used, DAO,
> Repository, UnitOfWork, Factory..
>
> -I can't find a good examples of data access pattern in C++, I know it should be independently of language but I couldn't find even a robust
> DAO pattern example with a good exception handling etc... Commonly are
> only two classes (obj1->obj2) on very small environment.

If someone knows good sources or any tips I will be very glad =D

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

My advice is search for c++ ORM(Object Relational Mapping) there are plenty ORM or DAL solutions on java like Hibernate, Datanucleus, SQLite ..

We are using Datanucleus and we are happy with it but i dont think datanucleus have a support for c++. Imho creating DAL form scratch is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem years ago. The list of ORM for C++ in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_object-relational_mapping_software) is very short and the most promising product is under GPL or you have to buy it.

We decide to develop our own ORM. There are several enterprise design patterns for it. We choose the way [obd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ODB_(C%2B%2B)) uses: Your tables was described from simple classes. The persistence and access of objects are handled from an database-manager. The most costliest todo is to write your own query-interface (if you don't wand to type clear sql in your code).